# Why my DateTime ModelState is invalid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model like this. Basically I have a field for a class name and two fields for start and end date in format of MM/dd/yyyy

```
namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class DateTimeViewModel
    {
        public DateTimeViewModel()
        {
            StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
            EndDate = new DateTime(StartDate.Year, 12, 31);
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my View

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.DateTimeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DateTimeViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

This is my `HttpPost` controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(WebApplication3.Models.DateTimeViewModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /// do something
    }

    return View();
}
```

The problem I am having now is that my ModelState.IsValid is returning FALSE when I enter a day like as in picture below:

[image]

It looks like every time I am entering a Day that is bigger than 12 then I'll get the validation error.

Do you know why or what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jasen: Not true. The OP has `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` which means the modelbinder will use the specified date format to parse the returned string date.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong here. Are you sure you've rebuilt your solution since apply the `DisplayFormat`? You will run into issues with this in browsers that support the `datetime` input type (which `EditorFor` will use), as the value then needs to be in ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD), but there's not many if any browsers that do support that input type and doesn't seem to be the issue here, regardless, as there's no custom control for the field.

Comment: @ Chris Yes I rebuilt an ran with same error. From what I am seeing, the validation fails because it thinks the Month is the Day and the Day is the Month. I just don't know how to work around it. What I am doing at the moment go get over this is to remove the ModelState.IsValid check in my controller and I know this is bad practice. I am hoping for a fix :(

Comment: Based on your comment, even though you have the format value for the date, you were saying that if you enter 31/12/21017, it works?

Comment: @ Brian - Yes, 31/12/2017 works

Comment: Your getting a server side error because the culture on your server expects dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. Change your culture or use a custom model binder

Answer (score 1):

Add the culture in your web config file:

```
 <system.web>

<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
```

And add in your global asax this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

Add `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` to your annotations.

Comment: That attribute is used to determine the `type` attribute for the input (i.e. it renders `<input type="date" ... />` in the browser). It has nothing to do with validation or binding.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved the issue for me.

Comment: Nonsense. `DataType(DataType.Date)` is not a validation attribute and has nothing to do with binding. Its sole purpose is to generate `type="date"` in the html when used in conjunction with `EditorFor()` which will display the browsers HTML-5 datepicker if the browser supports it (only in Chrome and Edge)

Comment: And OP is not wanting the HTML-5 datepicker (understandable because of its limited support). The issue is the culture on the server does not match the date format